# Unable to make reference to object in build.sbt, "error: not found: value hooks"

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to add gulp to my Play application, I have created a `PlayRunHook` object that should allow me to trigger the `gulp` command, but when I do `sbt run` I'm getting an error saying it could not find the object. Here is my hook:

```
package hooks

object Gulp extends CommandHook {

  override def beforeStarted(): Unit = {
    exec("gulp")
  }
}
```

And then in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.14",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.5.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-netty-server" % "2.5.0"
)

PlayKeys.playRunHooks += hooks.Gulp()
```

But I get:

```
build.sbt:18: error: not found: value hooks
PlayKeys.playRunHooks += hooks.Gulp()
```

Comment: It was helpful but not how I fixed my problem, I used `taskKey` instead. I will accept your answer as it answers the question as to why build.sbt cannot find the value `hooks` (code needs to be in `project/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create Gulp `object` **in** `project/` **directory** like below:

```
import play.sbt.PlayRunHook
import sbt._

object Gulp {
  def apply(base: File): PlayRunHook = {

    object GulpProcess extends PlayRunHook {

      override def beforeStarted(): Unit = {
        Process("gulp", base).run
      }
    }

    GulpProcess
  }
}
```

Then in your `build.sbt`:

```
PlayKeys.playRunHooks += Gulp(baseDirectory.value)
```

For more details check this [guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTCookbook#Hooking-into-Plays-dev-mode).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I actually went with the accepted answer in the end, this alternative answer will trigger your `gulp bundle` command every time  a request is made to your app. By using the `PlayRunHook` approach, you get different lifecycle hooks to hook into, and in the end I hooked into `beforeStarted` (as done in the accepted answer) to trigger `gulp watch` when starting the app.

Down the line I may alter this to do `gulp watch` in development and `gulp build` when deploying, though I am not at that stage yet.

---

The accepted answer explains why `build.sbt` cannot find the value `hooks` (the code needs to be in the directory `project/`), however to solve my issue of wanting to run `gulp bundle` during compile, I went with this solution:

```
import sbt._

// ...

lazy val gulp = taskKey[Unit]("Build frontend assets")
gulp := {
  println("gulp bundle" !!)
}

compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(gulp)
```